# is a class declaration before base-clause a valid forward declaration?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, forward-declaration

I'm not sure if my question title is the most appropriate and I will change it happily to something clearer if I get adequate suggestion.

In a C++ video whose subject is not the one here, I saw this definition:

```cpp
#include <vector>

// before ":" V is forward declared, it's enough for std::vector?
// node in a tree
struct V : std::vector<V> {};
```

(comments are my own).

My understanding is that it is possible to have this seemingly circular declaration, because at the `base-clause` location, `struct V` is already (forward) declared.

But is it legal C++ as I don't find that [class declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) is explicit about this.

`forward declaration` is defined by itself (`struct V;`, then you can declare a `std::vector<V>)` but not in the full class declaration syntax.

The wording in [derived class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class):

> Any class type (**whether declared with class-key class or struct**) may be declared as derived...

(bold mine)
seems to imply that `class-key class` or `class-key struct` (without ending `;`) are already full declarations. Is it true, is it more explicit in the standard?

If yes, it may give me opportunities for interesting designs, so I would like to be sure that it's legal.

[EDIT] a more explicit example, without `std::vector`

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct refwrapper {
    T* wrapped;
    virtual ~refwrapper() = default;
};

template <typename T>
struct plainwrapper {
    T wrapped;
    virtual ~plainwrapper() = default;
};

// OK? R is declared at the base-clause
struct R : refwrapper<R> {};

// KO P is incomplete at the base-clause
// struct P: plainwrapper<P>
// {};
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/PaWPqvM8a)

Comment: `std::vector` isn't really designed to be inherited from (no virtual destructor for one thing). And inheriting from the standard containers are seldom useful. What is the original problem that you want to solve by inheriting from `std::vector<V>`?

Comment: I just take the example as it from the video (and I agree with you). You can do that with any template class holding only pointer or reference to `V`. For the context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKKmPAQFNgE. So far, it's only an intuition that it can be used in practice (inheriting from template classes holding ref or pointer to the base).

Comment: Ah, so it's the more general case? Then it *is* useful and commonly used, and is called [the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Just not so much for `std::vector`.

Comment: I wouldn't have put it in the same category as the CRTP, as I use it generally with V being also template (thus the rules of declaration are not the same, aren't they)? I have to think  it through...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude inheriting from a class without a virtual destructor **is legal**. However, you must be careful not to destruct it through a base class pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class name is visible to lookup immediately after the identifier. See [[basic.scope.pdecl]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#3.sentence-1).

However, as usual, until the closing `}` of the class definition the class is incomplete. The base class specifier is not an exception as some so-called *complete class contexts* are.

Using a type as base class requires it to be complete. Therefore `std::vector<V>` will be instantiated by the use as base class specifier, where `V` is still incomplete.

Generally instantiating a standard library template with an incomplete type as template argument causes undefined behavior.

However, since C++17 `std::vector` is one of the exceptions: It is permitted to instantiate `std::vector` with an incomplete type as template argument as long as the type is completed before any member function of the `std::vector` specialization is referenced.

So yes, `struct V : std::vector<V> {};` is valid since C++17 since it doesn't reference any member of `std::vector<V>` before the closing `}`.

Comment: `std::vector` is really not the subject. I may edit the question to focus it on the recurring declaration. Yet your link may answer the question. I just not understand the idea of `locus` and if it de facto implies the the type is declared, though not defined.

Comment: @Oersted You can read through the name lookup rules and how the "_locus_" is used in them [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup). However, the rules are rather complex. The point is that anything lexically after `class V` will consider the declaration of `V` in name lookup of the identifier `V`. It is the same as for variables, where the locus is immediately after the declarator, e.g. `unsigned char x = f(&x);`.